# Removing custom markers (Google Maps Directions API)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Below script does a great job at displaying a map, taking user input as far as a start location is concerned, and then showing custom icons and drawing a route using a polyline between both the start and destination.

This works fine the first time someone enters a location and the route is plotted on the map. However, the second (and third, and fourth) time someone selects a starting location, it correctly draws the icon and route for the new starting location, but the marker for the previous location is not removed. 
For the life of me I can't figure out how to get it to remove that first start location marker.

If anyone could help me out with removing the first marker if/when a second location is entered I'd be grateful!

Code below:

```
var map;

document.getElementById('route_distance').setAttribute("style", "display: none");

function initMap() {

  var amsterdam = {lat: 52.370216, lng: 4.895168};
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: amsterdam,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: amsterdam,
    icon: '/images/mapicons/dejong-marker-2.svg',
    map: map,
  });

    // Create the DIV to hold the control and call the ZoomControl() constructor
    var zoomControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var zoomControl = new ZoomControl(zoomControlDiv, map);

    zoomControlDiv.index = 1;
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(zoomControlDiv);

    function ZoomControl(controlDiv, map) {

        // Creating divs & styles for custom zoom control
        controlDiv.style.padding = '14px';

        // Set CSS for the control wrapper
        var controlWrapper = document.createElement('div');
        controlWrapper.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
        controlWrapper.style.borderStyle = 'none';
        controlWrapper.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        controlWrapper.style.textAlign = 'center';
        controlWrapper.style.width = '20px'; 
        controlWrapper.style.height = '40px';
        controlDiv.appendChild(controlWrapper);

        // Set CSS for the zoomIn
        var zoomInButton = document.createElement('div');
        zoomInButton.style.width = '15px'; 
        zoomInButton.style.height = '15px';
        zoomInButton.style.marginBottom = '20px';
        /* Change this to be the .png image you want to use */
        zoomInButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url("/images/mapicons/plus.svg")';
        controlWrapper.appendChild(zoomInButton);

        // Set CSS for the zoomOut
        var zoomOutButton = document.createElement('div');
        zoomOutButton.style.width = '15px'; 
        zoomOutButton.style.height = '15px';
        zoomOutButton.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
        /* Change this to be the .png image you want to use */
        zoomOutButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url("/images/mapicons/minus.svg")';
        controlWrapper.appendChild(zoomOutButton);

        // Setup the click event listener - zoomIn
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomInButton, 'click', function() {
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
        });

        // Setup the click event listener - zoomOut
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomOutButton, 'click', function() {
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
        });  

    }

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);

    return map;
}

function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
    var directionmarker = '/images/mapicons/start_icon.svg';
    this.map = map;
    this.originPlaceId = null;
    this.destinationPlaceId = 'ChIJVXealLU_xkcRja_At0z9AGY';
    this.travelMode = 'DRIVING';
    this.UnitSystem = 'METRIC';
    this.departure_time = 'now';
    var originInput = document.getElementById('origin-input');
    this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      suppressMarkers: true,
      map: map,
      polylineOptions: {
        strokeColor: "#004996",
        strokeWeight: "4",
      },
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
    });
    this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    originInput, {
        placeIdOnly: true
    });
    this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
}

// Sets a listener when the input fields to change the filter type on Places Autocomplete.
AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(autocomplete, mode) {
    var me = this;
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.place_id) {
            window.alert("Select an option from the list.");
            return;
        }
        if (mode === 'ORIG') {
            me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
        } else {
            me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
        }
        me.travelMode = 'DRIVING';
        me.route();
    });
};

AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
    if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
        return;
    }
    var me = this;
    this.directionsService.route({
        origin: { 'placeId': this.originPlaceId },
        destination: { 'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId },
        travelMode: this.travelMode,
    }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            var theDistance = Math.round((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value) / 1000) + ' KM';
            var theTime = Math.round((response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value) / 60) + ' min';
            document.getElementById('route_distance').setAttribute("style", "display: inline");
            document.getElementById('route_distance').innerHTML = theDistance + ' ~ ' + theTime;
            me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            var route_start = response.routes[0].legs[0].start_location;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: route_start,
                map: map,
                icon: '/images/mapicons/start-icon.svg',
                zIndex: 5
            });
        } else {
            window.alert('Could not display route: ' + status);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: To remove a marker you need to set the marker map reference to null, like this `marker.setMap(null);` which means you might need to save a reference of the created markers

Comment: @claudio that's the exact thing I'm having issues with. I found the `marker.setMap(null);` part, I just don't know and can't figure out how to save a reference to the earlier markers without completely rebuilding the thing to use some sort of marker push construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving a reference to all the created markers that you want to delete. Create a markers array that will contain a reference to all the markers created.

```
var markers = [];
```

When adding the marker, instead of `var marker = new google.m...`  save a reference on the markers array

```
markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    position: route_start,
    map: map,
    icon: '/images/mapicons/start-icon.svg',
    zIndex: 5
}));
```

Create a method that loops the markers array and sets the map to null (deletes) and this method when needed.

```
function removeMarkers() {
    for (var i in markers) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];
}
```